# How to give permanent usb permission to an android application

Tags: android

I am developing an application which requires permanent permission for using usb host, on every restart the application will require fresh permission for using USB is there any way one can bypass the dialogbox and give the application permissions it needs.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, change ur project **Target SDK** to 21. It will work.

**Remember**: Min SDK and Target SDK Levels, both are different thing.

Comment: Why? Any more info on this please?

Comment: Even with Target SDK 21 it doesn't work.